# Verilog counter does not trigger for different clock signals

Tags: verilog, counter, clock

I'm trying to write a counter that simply tracks the positive edge of a clock and increments a variable when it does. The caveat is this circuit must switch between different clock sources. The counter and clock multiplexer function as intended for the default clock in simulation, but the counter does not seem to be seeing the positive edges of the second clock signal. I've tested the multiplexer on its own, and it passes the clock signal through correctly. Any thoughts?

The top module:

```
module hw1_top(reset, updown, inp, clkSwitch, Clk100MHz, testClock2, out);
input reset, updown, Clk100MHz, testClock2;
input [15:0] inp;
input [3:0] clkSwitch;

output [15:0] out;

wire muxtoclk;

ClockMux mux(
    .c1(Clk100MHz),
    .c2(testClock2),
    .switch(clkSwitch),
    .cOut(muxtoclk)
);

UDCounter counter(
    .RST(reset),
    .UD(updown),
    .INP(inp),
    .CLK(muxtoclk),
    .OUT(out)
);  
endmodule
```

Counter:

```
module UDCounter(RST, UD, INP, CLK, OUT);
input RST, UD, CLK; //1 bit inputs
input [15:0] INP; //16 bit input

output reg [15:0] OUT; //16 bit output, must be reg for sequential

initial
    OUT <= INP; //when we start, counter initializes to whatever the input is

always@(posedge CLK or posedge RST) //on every positive edge of the clock cycle, or if reset is triggered...
    if(RST == 1'b1) //if reset is high, set counter back to the initial input
        OUT <= INP;
    else //if reset isn't triggered...
        if(UD == 1'b0) //if up/down is in up position, count up
            begin
                OUT <= OUT + 1;
            end
        else //if in down, count down
            begin
                OUT <= OUT -1;
            end
endmodule
```

Multiplexer:

```
module ClockMux(c1,c2,switch,cOut);switch,cOut);
input c1,c2;
input [3:0] switch;

output reg cOut;

always@(switch,c1,c2) //updates whenever the switch or clock changes
    case(switch)
        4'b0000: cOut <= c1;
        4'b0001: cOut <= c2;
    endcase
 endmodule
```

Top level testbench and waveform:

```
module hw1_top_tb();
reg reset, updown, Clk100MHz, testClock2;
reg [15:0] inp;

wire [15:0] out;
reg [3:0] switchValue;

hw1_top topmod(
    .reset(reset),
    .updown(updown),
    .inp(inp),
    .clkSwitch(switchValue),
    .Clk100MHz(Clk100MHz),
    .out(out)
);

initial Clk100MHz = 0;
always #5 Clk100MHz = ~Clk100MHz;

initial testClock2 = 0;
always #3 testClock2 = ~testClock2;

initial begin
    reset = 0; updown = 0; inp = 16'b0; switchValue = 4'b0000; 
    #10;
    reset = 1; updown = 0; inp = 16'b0; switchValue = 4'b0000; 
    #10; //toggles the reset briefly to clear dc's

    reset = 0; updown = 0; inp = 16'b0; switchValue = 4'b0000;
    #40;
    reset = 1; updown = 0; inp = 16'b0; switchValue = 4'b0001; //counter is not listening here
    #10;
    reset = 0; updown = 0; inp = 16'b0; switchValue = 4'b0001; //counter is not listening here
    #23;
    reset = 1; updown = 0; inp = 16'b0; switchValue = 4'b0000; //when we switch back, it's doing great
    #13;
    reset = 0; updown = 0; inp = 16'b0; switchValue = 4'b0000;
    #23;
    $finish;
end
 endmodule
```

[image: Waveform in question]

Comment: Double-check all your port connections

Comment: Switching between clocks is a very difficult circuit to get right. The way you do it will give you clock glitches or 'runt' clocks. It will work in simulation but in real logic you should be prepared to find you have 'issues' with your counter. e.g. you will miss clock pulses or worse: your counter jumps between values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never connected `testClock2` in your instantiation `topmod` of `hw1_top`:

```
hw1_top topmod(
    .reset(reset),
    .updown(updown),
    .inp(inp),
    .clkSwitch(switchValue),
    .Clk100MHz(Clk100MHz),
    .testClock2(testClock2), // this is missing
    .out(out)
);
```

Comment: Certainly, but for what he's specifically asking for, its what's missing. Oldfart summed up the higher level problems and there are additional issues with his code. However, as this is clearly a homework problem, I simply wanted to point out the missing piece and hopefully allow his educational institution correct the other conceptual mistakes which are less easy to address in a short so answer.

Comment: That fixed the specific issue! Thanks for the second pair of eyes, and I'll be sure to discuss the overall design more closely with the professor. Thank you all for the help!